# NAO Object Recognition and Picking

Tags: python, nao-robot

I want NAO to recognize general objects and grasp its as this movie -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSKRgasUEko

Using a library "RedBall Tracker", I have easily developed the system that Nao recognize red ball and grasp it.
Can you do the same on general objects?

Comment: Hey, How were you able to grasp an object. I've been unable to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you share the code that grasp red ball on the ground?

Answer (score 0):

In the movie, NAO doesn't recognize the object as duck, but just an unknown object.
That said, you should look at this [OpenCV tutoriel](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/).
You will learn how to recognize specific objects as watch or watever you want !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is [via Choregraphe](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/tutos/recognize_objects.html#choregraphe-tuto-learn-object), you can make Nao recognize objects in a few minutes.

(you can download choregraphe from [here](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/us-en/downloads))